# How to paste groups of images from a list on top of a base image with the Pillow module?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, python-imaging-library

All images are in PNG format.

```
 from PIL import Image
```

First of all, I would have a base image:

```
image_base = Image.open (image.png)
```

Second, I would have a list of my desired combinations (each string is linked to an image path) to paste **over** the base image, such that combinations [0] [0], combinations [0] [1], and combinations [0] [2] pasted on top of the base image would compose a final image of the 8 desired (look at the first index, it goes up to 7).

```
list = ['combinations [0] [0]', 'combinations [0] [1]', 'combinations [0] [2]', 'combinations [1] [0]', 'combinations [1] [1 ] ',' combinations [1] [2] ',' combinations [2] [0] ',' combinations [2] [1] ',' combinations [2] [2] ',' combinations [3] [0 ] ',' combinations [3] [1] ',' combinations [3] [2] ',' combinations [4] [0] ',' combinations [4] [1] ',' combinations [4] [2 ] ',' combinations [5] [0] ',' combinations [5] [1] ',' combinations [5] [2] ',' combinations [6] [0] ',' combinations [6] [1 ] ',' combinations [6] [2] ',' combinations [7] [0] ',' combinations [7] [1] ',' combinations [7] [2] ']
```

My goal would be to figure out how to iterate through the list and paste each combination with the same first index above the base image. In this case, every 3 values ​​in the list, create a composition.

Comment: you have `image.paste(other_image)` to put one image on another. And if you use it with `for`-loop and sublist `list[:3]` then you can put first three images. The same with `list[3:6]`, etc. `list[n:n+3]` or `list[ 3*x : 3*x+3 ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is situation when `range(len())` can be useful because it can use `step` in `range()`

```
for i in range(0, len(list), 3):
    print(list[i:i+3])
```

and it gives lists

```
['combinations [0] [0]', 'combinations [0] [1]', 'combinations [0] [2]']
['combinations [1] [0]', 'combinations [1] [1]', 'combinations [1] [2]']
['combinations [2] [0]', 'combinations [2] [1]', 'combinations [2] [2]']
['combinations [3] [0]', 'combinations [3] [1]', 'combinations [3] [2]']
['combinations [4] [0]', 'combinations [4] [1]', 'combinations [4] [2]']
['combinations [5] [0]', 'combinations [5] [1]', 'combinations [5] [2]']
['combinations [6] [0]', 'combinations [6] [1]', 'combinations [6] [2]']
['combinations [7] [0]', 'combinations [7] [1]', 'combinations [7] [2]']
```

And now you can use every list to create image

```
new = base.copy()

for path in list[i:i+3]:
    image = Image.open(path)
    new.paste(image, ....)
```

---

PIL doc: [Image.paste()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html?highlight=paste#PIL.Image.Image.paste)

---

**EDIT:**

Nested loops.

```
for i in range(0, len(list), 3):
    #print(list[i:i+3])
    new = base.copy()

    for path in list[i:i+3]:
        image = Image.open(path)
        new.paste(image, ....)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it works correctly. But, what if you wanted to iterate through all the sublists automatically?

Comment: Okay, I resolved this with two counters: one for a new list_of_lists that have all groups of 3 and  another for i value :)

Comment: I don't understand what is problem - you have all in answer - you put second `for`-loop inside first `for`-loop. That's all. I added code.